# Grouping objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, grouping, paperjs

I'm working on a visualization of clouds user paperjs, and I am having trouble figuring out the most efficient way to create groups dynamically.

As one cloud shape intersects another, they become one group (compoundPath in paperjs), which works fine, but there can be many different groups, which is where my confusion comes in.

Currently I check for intersection, and when two intersect, I create a new tmpGroup referencing those two.

```
Cloud.prototype.checkIntersection = function() {
    for(var i=0;i<cloudArray.length;i++){                       //go through all clouds
        if(this.path !== cloudArray[i].path){                   //prevent self-check
            if(this.path.intersects(cloudArray[i].path)){       //if intersects
                tmpGrp = [this.path,cloudArray[i].path];        //create a tmpGrp
                groupClouds(tmpGrp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then I can't figure it out...

```
function groupClouds(tmpGrp){
    if(grps.length > 0){                //if there are multiple distinct groups
        for(var i=0;i<grps.length;i++){ //loop through all groups
            //if(tmpGrp !== grps[i]){       //broken, expected to be able to compare
                                            //arrays easier in JS
                grps.push(tmpGrp);      //add pair of intersecting paths to a new group
            //}
        }
    }else{
        grps[0] = tmpGrp;               //if none are defined, the first will be the tmpGrp
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any advice in a situation like this? An idea was proposed to me to create an array that could reference each group like this:

```
Grp[i][group] = [1,2,5] //all objects in pair
Grp[i][pool] = [3,4]    //all objects remaining
```

But I can't seem to implement that correctly.

Comment: A good solution would be to use a recursive function: `for each cloud: if intersects the given cloud: create a new group and recall the function (with the new group as the given cloud)`

Comment: I could help you better if you make a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/).

Comment: I think the recursive method might be enough for me to go off of, it seems like that solves the problem of how I was thinking about it.